# Two network connections - how do I control what traffic goes to/from each of them?

Tags: windows, networking, firewall, network-shares, firefox

I have two internet connections on my computer (one WiFi and one with ethernet cable).

The issue is that I want to make sure that one of the connections (the WiFi) is "reserved" to only handle all the Firefox traffic. No other traffic is allowed to go through that connection.

I want the other connection (ethernet cable) to take care of ALL the rest of traffic.

Please point me in the right direction. How do I fix this?

I´m on Windows 7.

Big THANK YOU, guys!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [WideCAP](http://widecap.ru/en/). It proxyfies everything. But it was not updated since 2009.

Another way is:
* - So, you have two networks: 192.168.1.0/24 (for everything) and 192.168.2.0/24 (for Firefox)
1. Use proxy (Let's say it's IP is 10.20.30.40)
2. Configure default route to use adapter #1 
3. Configure route to proxy on adapret #2 like that

```
route add 10.20.30.40 MASK 255.255.255.255 192.168.2.1 METRIC 1 IF 2
```

4. Set outcoming firewall chain to On and configure a rule to deny everything for adapter #2

And another way (googled it just now - [ForceBindIP](http://old.r1ch.net/stuff/forcebindip/)). - Never checked this software, so on your risk

Comment: Thanks for your reply filimonic!

Is proxifying the fastest, easiest and safest way to do it? No possibility to fix it somehow with internal firewall rules?

Comment: @Skaggmannen updated post. check ForceBindIP, but on your own risk. And configure Outcoming firewall rules for your 'Firefox adapter'

Comment: And check [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/117890/how-to-force-an-application-to-use-a-specific-network-card/)

Comment: I´ve already been experimenting with ForceBindIP and it works well for its designed purpose but I think it has its limitations for my specific objective. I can easyily forcebind Mozilla to one of my network adapters but how can I be sure that no other application will use the same network adapter for their traffic?

There´s a lot of applications and passive system processes that may choose the same path as the one that is forcebindIP´ed  to Firefox. To ForceBindIP all of those applications and system processes seems to take an overwhelming amount of time

Hmmm.. Suggestions?

Thanks a lot :-)